# Select Random Row from SQL Using PHP but from specific point to point ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am making sort of Quiz project and I want to select and display random rows from database but only from ID 5 to ID 25 in order display 20 questions also update the state from not-displayed to displayed.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions_Library (no idea)');
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row['question'];
    }
}
```

[Database visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjjdu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should LIMIT your result set to 20 then.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions_Library LIMIT 20');
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row['question'];
    }
}

//Update the state of questions returned to displayed
```

You might also want to select only those that have not been displayed

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions_Library WHERE displayed = 0 LIMIT 20');
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row['question'];
    }
}

//Update the state of questions returned to displayed
```